# Multiple image Share in Email

Tags: java, android

here I am trying to share multiple image in email.i have done following code.

```
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"chirag.solanki@gmail.com"});
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "That's Testing of list");
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imgUri);
            shareIntent.setType("image*//**//**//**//*");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images to.."));
```

all are working fine but attachment getting null.why this happend that I don't know please help me if any one have any feasible solution.

Note :: Image Store in Server not in Local.Image path is like follwing

image path :: http://first.com/list/project_images/thumb/55c068d54eafb1438673109.jpg

here imgUri is ArrayList of URI

Comment: your image path does not point to a image, but to some html.

Comment: Not sure if this can solve your problem: try: `shareIntent.setType("image/*")`. Also make sure that `imgUri` isn't null

Answer (score 0):

I would make it like this(with Uri.parse it works for me):

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(photoPath));
```

Comment: here imgUri is Arraylist of Uri.than how it's possible..?